# UIView to make an arm wave

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, animation, uiview

I'm trying to make an arm wave effect (Hello!) with UIView animations, but it snaps back to the beginning when the last one goes off.  I want the wave to go back and forth.

First keyframe: Rotation 30˚
Second keyframe: Rotation -30˚
Third keyframe: SHOULD BE Rotation 0˚

```
    arm.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0);
    float x = arm.frame.origin.x + arm.frame.size.width;
    float y = arm.frame.origin.y + arm.frame.size.height;
    arm.layer.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, arm.frame.size.width, arm.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView arm];


    float degrees = 30.0;
    float radians = (degrees/90.0)*M_PI;
    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:4.0f delay:0.0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat
    animations:^{            
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration:.5 animations:^{
            arm.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
        }];
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:.5 relativeDuration:.75 animations:^{
            arm.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-radians);
        }];
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:1.25 relativeDuration:.5 animations:^{
            arm.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
        }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you used up the whole animation on the first two frames of the keyframe animation. These are *relative* times and *relative* durations; they must all be less than 1!

So, on the first one you use up half the animation (`.5`).

On the second one you start halfway through the animation (`.5`) and then you use up the entire rest of the animation (`.75` is larger than `.5` which is all you've got left).

So the third one never happens. And in any case it's completely nuts: you can't *have* a relative start time of `1.75` because `1` is the end of the animation. Read the docs:

> This value must be in the range 0 to 1, where 0 represents the start of the overall animation and 1 represents the end of the overall animation. For example, for an animation that is two seconds in duration, specifying a start time of 0.5 causes the animations to begin executing one second after the start of the overall animation.